# Merge Audio and Video using ffmpeg - Python Lib

Tags: python, audio, video, ffmpeg

i have tried

```
import ffmpeg
video = ffmpeg.input('video.mp4')
audio = ffmpeg.input('audio.mp3')
ffmpeg.merge_outputs(video, audio).run()
```

and it returns

```
TypeError: Expected incoming stream(s) to be of one of the following types: ffmpeg.nodes.OutputStream; got <class 'ffmpeg.nodes.FilterableStream'>
```

and i have tried

```
import ffmpeg
video = ffmpeg.input('video.mp4')
audio = ffmpeg.input('audio.mp3')
ffmpeg.concat(video, audio, v=1, a=1).output('finished_video.mp4').run()
```

and it returns

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

also i did try

```
import subprocess    
subprocess.run("ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -c copy output.mp4")
```

and it returns

```
'ffmpeg' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

how can i do it right ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine The video and audio files in ffmpeg-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973205/how-to-combine-the-video-and-audio-files-in-ffmpeg-python)

Comment: no it dosen't i've tried that as well and it did not work for me `ffmpeg is not recognized as an internal or external command`